# Removing BACS instructions from email notiications in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, email-notifications

On my WooCommerce web shop I have enabled the payment getaway **"Direct bank transfer"**.

In `Woocommerce` --> `Settings` --> `Checkout` --> `BACS` there is a field called **"instruction"**. This textfield is added to the **thank you** page, which is good. 
But it's also added to the **costumer-order-completed email**, which I dont want.

I already tried to understand the [php](/questions/tagged/php) files which are responsible for  email notification, but I have no clue to avoid the display for this "instructions" text.

How can I remove "instructions" text for BACS payment gateway in email notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom function hooked in [**`woocommerce_email_order_details`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_email_before_order_table) action hook that will remove the **Direct Bank Transfer (BACS) instructions from email notifications**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', function(){
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Payment_Gateways' ) ) return;

    $gateways = WC_Payment_Gateways::instance(); // gateway instance
    $available_gateways = $gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['bacs'] ) )
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( $available_gateways['bacs'], 'email_instructions' ), 10, 3 );
}, 1 );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works for WooCommerce version 2.6.x and 3+

Comment: That did the job, ty!

Answer (score 0):

You can solved this in the line 38

```html
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

File: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/customer-completed-order.php

Comment: i commited the line `//do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );` But it has no effect on the email. Am i doing it wrong?